# Unable to Query IsPrivateDraft in EmailMessage through data loader or REST API

Tags: rest-api, emailmessage

We are trying to get the data from EmailMessage and looking to have the fields `IsPrivateDraft`, `LastOpenedDate`, `FirstOPenedDate`; and while we can query these through developer console we are unable to query these in data loader and using the REST API.

We have verified, and the access to these fields is set to true for Visible and Read-only

Would you be able to tell is there any restriction?

Answer (score 0):

LastOpenDate and FirstOpenedDate become available when you turn on [email tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_tracking_parent.htm&type=5). Even without email tracking, we're able to query them via REST API and/or via SOQL. (The values of these fields won't be set without tracking)

IsPrivateDraft is trickier. It only shows up as a field available via REST API when you [enable drafts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_enabling_email_drafts.htm&type=5) for Cases. (This requires email-to-case to be turned on).

To test availability of a field via API, use the `describe` "command" with EmailMessage as the entity. Resource URI:

`/services/data/<api version>/sobjects/EmailMessage/describe`

Output with v46 API, email tracking turned on and drafts enabled

[image]